# How to let an iOS app to automatically recognize from which app store it was downloaded from at launch?

Tags: ios, app-store

To be more specific, we have an app that we would like to deploy on the Apple App Store in multiple countries. For certain countries, we would like the app to connect to our servers via different connectivity configurations. For example, if our app downloaded from the App Store in France is launched, we would like for the app to know that and use the connectivity optimized for France automatically. We don’t want to maintain multiple versions of the app for different countries. And there would be no in-app purchase implemented on our app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really detect where it was downloaded from without distributing individual builds for each app store.

One option you could look at is to simply check NSLocale (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale)

You can get the language and country code that the device is set to from this, which should work correctly in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Locale`, and according to it make configurations:

```
let locale = Locale.current
print(locale.regionCode)
```

> Output: "FR" for France, "US" for the USA, "GB" for Great Britain etc.

**[Here](https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273)** the full list identifiers.

Hope it helps.